# reinstalling /var/lib/dpkg

Tags: apt, data-recovery

The hard drive on my server that contains /var crashed yesterday. I do not have backups for everything in `/var/lib`.

Regarding the list of packages installed, I have a backup file using the following command from the day of the crash:

```
dpkg-query - show - showformat = '$ {Package} \ n'
```

How to reset apt and dpkg settings to be able to re-install and update the system?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The whole state of the package management is kept in there. If it's lost, there's no way to 'rebuild' this database in a reasonable way. It keeps track of more than just what packages are installed, e.g. configuration choices (debconf). Recovering this from (earlier) backups may lead to other issues too - as the system state may have changed and the backup is invalid in such a case. This will result in conflicts later.

Only restore `/var/lib/dpkg` from backup if you know nothing has been changed concerning the package management in the meantime.